# Why is netcore 3 have so many issues with InProcess ANCM?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-3.0

We were happily using InProcess with 2.2 but when we upgraded to AspNetZero 8.0.0 (using netcore3.0) - we suddenly had TONS of issues that seem to be solved by changing the `hostingModel` to `OutOfProcess` from `InProcess`. The behavior is also inconsistant. On my machine, I have no problem with either model but on 3 other developers they are constantly getting this:

[image: 503 error when InProcess]

Here's what that error looks like in the log:

[image: InProcess error]

What's more, is that the other developers have found that it keeps reverting back to InProcess or rather that the web.config value for `hostingModel` keeps changing and they aren't trying to change it because it stops them from working.

So, the question is why? I would prefer to use InProcess. Is there something wrong here?

Comment: The call stack shows Castle related functions, so I don't think the issues have nothing to do with Castle. Keep in mind 3.0 is a large step ahead with tons of breaking changes, so unless all dependencies you use are well upgraded to bet 3.0 compatible, issues are expected. The web.config related issues should be investigated further by those developers (with tools like Process Monitor) to learn where the changes come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here doesn't seem to have anything to do with Castle. We had to switch from using InProcess to using OutOfProcess. Doing so allowed the site to function again.